# Raspberry Pi / Octopi USB Camera Setup: What does this mean and how do I use it?

Tags: raspberry-pi, octoprint

I'm very new to Raspberry Pi, and have no prior notable experience with Linux so this is all new to me...

Octoprint is a 3D printer spooler that you can run on your raspberry pi. One of the features on Octoprint is the ability to setup a USB camera to view either still images or a stream of your print.

I am using the Octopi prepackaged Octoprint image.

Octoprint's github contains the following info referring to my USB camera. But I have no idea how to implement this.

Hama PC-Webcam "AC-150" on Raspberry Pi

`./mjpg_streamer -o output_http.so -w ./www -i input_uvc.so -y -r 640x480 -f 10`

https://github.com/foosel/OctoPrint/wiki/Webcams-known-to-work

I'm guessing this is an easy command that I enter via console, but I've winged few commands with no luck. Can someone shed some light on how I use this? Like I said I'm an absolute beginner with the pi...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. `camera_usb_options="-r VGA -f 10 -y"`
2. `sudo service octoprint stop`
3. `fuser /dev/video0`

   1. `/dev/video0: **1871m**`
4. `$ ps axl | grep **1871** *Change this number by yours*`
5. `$ kill -9 **1871**`
6. `./mjpg_streamer -i "input_uvc.so $camera_usb_options" -o "output_http.so -w ./www"`
7. `sudo service octoprint start`